# Adding new table to ER Diagram

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I created database and ER Diagram. Then I added new table to exsisting database. Now I would like have this table in my ER Diagram. How can I do it? Have I to create new Diagram? Of course I can use the table tool on the vertical toolbar, but if I have new table I suppose that is better way to get this table in Diagram.

Answer (score 2):

First, always upgrade to the [latest MySQL Workbench version](http://mysqlworkbench.org) (at the time being 6.0.9 with 6.1 around the corner).

I assume you created your EER diagram from the database via reverse engineering. Any time you want to update either the model or the database (schema) run the synchronization in MySQL Workbench. Open a model and go to `Database -> Synchronize Model...`. This is a two-way tool (model to schema and schema to model), but you can manually define the direction (or to ignore a change). Once you have synchronized your changed schema the new table will appear in the catalog tree where you can drag it to a diagram.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a pane on the left titled `Catalog Tree` in the tab for your existing EER diagram.
You can drag and drop your new table onto the existing diagram. If the table isn't listed, do a refresh on the dbname in the tree view.

Comment: It works for me using version 6.0. Did you refresh(right click)?

Comment: yes, of course. But I'm using version 5.2 CE. Maybe this version is too old?